# continue for loop execution after exception

Tags: c#, wpf

I want the for loop to continue execution if an exception occurs (99 out of 100, wiil be conection problem to portal), meaning move to connecting to next portal.

I thought using I `finally` compined with a `goto` but I dislike using `goto`.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < Portals.Count; i++)
{
    try
       {
        if (!Portals[i].IsConnected)
          {
             Portals[i].Connect();
             ///..Permorm variours actioms...
          }
        }
    catch 
        {
         Window7 win = new Window7();
         win.label1.Content = "Connect to Portal " + (i + 1).ToString() + " Failed..";
         win.ShowDialog();
         return;
        }
```

Comment: remove (comment out) "return" in the "catch"

Comment: Never use `goto`. Change `return` with `continue`, then it will skip to the next iteration.

Comment: @scheien I don't see any `goto` here. also there is no need to use `continue` if there is no more code below it.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: No, but he said he thought of it, and that is enough for that statement :-) Sure the `continue` may not be needed, but it does not hurt to have it there and it does show that we're skipping to the next iteration.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko just test and realised..what an idiot I am thanks

Comment: @scheien Oops, I missed that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to continue with the code placed after the try/catch use this :
(simply remove the return; statement)

```
for (int i = 0; i < Portals.Count; i++)
{
    try
    {
        if (!Portal[i].IsConnected)
        {
            Portal[i].Connect();
            ///..Permorm variours actioms...
        }
    }
    catch 
    {
        Window7 win = new Window7();
        win.label1.Content = "Connect to Portal " + (i + 1).ToString() + " Failed..";
        win.ShowDialog();
    }
    // TODO - Some more code here
}
```

If you wish to stop that iteration if an Exception occurs, simply replace your return by a continue :

```
for (int i = 0; i < Portals.Count; i++)
{
    try
    {
        if (!Portal[i].IsConnected)
        {
            Portal[i].Connect();
            ///..Permorm variours actioms...
        }
    }
    catch 
    {
        Window7 win = new Window7();
        win.label1.Content = "Connect to Portal " + (i + 1).ToString() + " Failed..";
        win.ShowDialog();
        continue;
    }
    // TODO - Some more code here
}
```

Comment: By the way, I noticed you were using `Portal[i]` isn't it supposed to be `Portals[i]` since you use `Portals.Count` ?